# Connecting the wort chiller to a sink on a lower level

Tags: wort-chiller

I'm considering brewing indoors this weekend, instead of my usual outdoor process in warmer times of the year.  Since the last time I brewed indoors, I've replaced my kitchen sink's faucet with one to which I'm reluctant to try to attach the wort chiller (immersion - copper coil).

A pond pump for recirculating water through the chiller is in my future plans, but that's not going to happen before this upcoming brew day.

I have a utility sink in the basement, and the hose reel is down there for winter storage anyway.  Could I hook up the hose in the basement and then run it up one level of stairs to my kitchen for the wort chiller?  There's no backflow preventer on the utility sink, could that cause problems?

Comment: I just got the aerator off the new faucet.  It doesn't fit my hose adapter.  I guess the hose will either be either up from the basement or in the back door tomorrow.

Comment: I'm happy to report that the hose from the basement worked just fine.  I managed to get things connected and disconnected with a small amount of spray and no hose water flowing back into my plumbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have sewer problems now, I don't see how you would run in to trouble.   It's pretty much like running your kitchen sink for 45 minutes.  Your water supply should be pressurized by your service provider.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem but I'd prepare in advance how I'd empty that hose once I am done.  Don't want to be dealing with that disaster as I am trying to deal with the wort at the same time.

If possible why not just bring the kettle down to the utility sink and hooking the chiller up down there may be a better option.

Comment: If it comes to it, I think I'd rather figure out how to get the hose adapter on my new kitchen faucet than carry hot wort down the stairs. Right now, I'm planning on turning off the water at the utility sink faucet and then removing the hose. I fully expect there will be spray from the bottom end of the hose when I do so, but it's in the laundry room so even if it sprays pretty violently it'll be OK.  Good point about the wort while I'm dealing with that--I'll make sure the wort is safely in the fermenter before I disconnect the hose.